# [ROS2] what is different between DeclareLaunchArgument and LaunchConfiguration

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had tested ros2 launch with arguments.
The arguments are successfully implemented using only set `LaunchConfiguration` exclude `DeclareLaunchArgument`.
For example, attached launch files worked excluding `DeclareLaunchArgument`

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, EnvironmentVariable
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

TURTLEBOT3_MODEL = os.environ['TURTLEBOT3_MODEL']

def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')
    urdf_file_name = 'turtlebot3_' + TURTLEBOT3_MODEL + '.urdf'
    print("urdf_file_name : {}".format(urdf_file_name))

    urdf = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_description'), 'urdf', urdf_file_name)

    return LaunchDescription([
        #DeclareLaunchArgument(
        #    'use_sim_time',
        #    default_value='false',
        #    description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            node_executable='robot_state_publisher',
            node_name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{' use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
            arguments=[urdf]),
    ])
```

However, most examples of ros2 launch are included `DeclareLaunchArgument` when user want to use arguments.
So, my main questions is What is different btw `LaunchConfiguration` and `DeclareLaunchArgument`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322874/%5Bros2%5D-what-is-different-between-declarelaunchargument-and-launchconfiguration/) by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2019-05-09

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`LaunchConfiguration` is local to the launch file and scoped.

`DeclareLaunchArgument` allows you to expose the argument outside of your launch file. Allowing them to be listed, set, or marked as required when a user launches it from the command line (using `ros2 launch`) or when including it from another launch file (using `IncludeLaunchDescription`).

A `LaunchConfiguration` cannot be required to be set when launching or including and it is not possible to set it when launching from the command line. You can set a `LaunchConfiguration` before including another launch file, but an argument is better if you want it to be reused.

EDIT:

Here's an example I threw together demonstrate based on comments to this answer:

```
import launch


def generate_launch_description():
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument('msg', default_value='hello world'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument('other'),
        launch.actions.LogInfo(msg=launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('msg')),
        launch.actions.LogInfo(msg=launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('other')),
    ])
```

If I try to launch it without arguments (`ros2 launch ./test.launch.py`) I get:

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Included launch description missing required argument 'other' (description: 'no description given'), given: []
```

That's because the `other` option has no default value and therefore is required.

I actually found out that the `--show-arguments` option was broken while testing this, so I'm not sure if that's what you ran into, but I open a pr to fix:

https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/pull/27

With that fix I can check the arguments (`ros2 launch -s ./test.launch.py`):

```
Arguments (pass arguments as '<name>:=<value>'):

    'msg':
        no description given
        (default: 'hello world')

    'other':
        no description given
```

I can run it if I specify `other` (`ros2 launch ./test.launch.py other:='lorem ipsum'`):

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [launch.actions.log_info]: hello world
[INFO] [launch.actions.log_info]: lorem ipsum
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2019-05-10**:
Thank you for comments :)
However, if I set `LaunchConfiguration` excluding `DeclareLaunchArgument`, I would access launch argument from the command line. If I erase `LaunchConfiguration`, I would not.
Furthermore, I couldn't find any arguments in launch file using `-s` or `--show-arguments` after activate `DeclareLaunchArgument`.
I have tested it in Ubuntu18.04 and ROS2 Dashing(master repo)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-05-17**:\

> if I set LaunchConfiguration excluding DeclareLaunchArgument, I would access launch argument from the command line. If I erase LaunchConfiguration, I would not.

I don't understand this, can you try to rephrase it?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-05-17**:
After fixing a bug I can see the arguments, so maybe you need to give more details? I updated my answer with my demo.

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2019-05-22**:
Thank you for updates. I could check launch arguments using `-s` and I clearly understand what is a different of them. Thanks again!

**Comment by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on 2019-11-20**:
I'm struggling with the concept of substitutions. In my simplified case:

```
urdf = DeclareLaunchArgument('urdf', default_value='file.urdf')
urdf_file  =  [launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('urdf')]
urdf_path =os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot_bringup'), 'urdf', urdf_file)
```

If launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('urdf') is passed as a list I get a `"join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'".`If I dont, I get join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'LaunchConfiguration' Is there an easy way to get the text value of the argument?

**Comment by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) on 2020-04-04**:
@fastestindian, Did you resolve it?

**Comment by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) on 2020-08-02**:
@fastestindian, It is the wrong way to deal with substitutions, once you have substitution the content of it cannot be used before all substitutions can be resolved. You either have to create a custom substitution or use an existing one:
https://github.com/ros2/launch/tree/master/launch/launch/substitutions

For your use-case, you can use `PathJoinSubstitution`, something like:

```
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution

...

urdf_path = PathJoinSubstitution(get_package_share_directory('robot_bringup'), 'urdf', launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('urdf'))
```